# Populate contact and opportunity lookup in Survey Response

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I created a survey in Voice of the Customer app. I included piped data as below :

[image]

I created a workflow to send an email when an opportunity is won:

[image]

I am able to see the piped data in the survey. But, the contact lookup and opportunity lookup is not getting populated in the survey response form :

[image]

Am I missing something?

How does these lookups get populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we send an email containing the survey, a survey activity is formed. This survey activity has a unique invitation link, regarding field (populated with opportunity in my case) and is tied to the survey.

When I submit the response, the survey response gets tied to this survey activity. Hence, we are able to tag survey responses with different opportunity records.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a similar workflow (or pre create/post create plugin) on create of survey response, to map the opportunity lookup value from survey in survey response as well.

Comment: Survey is like a master survey, it can be sent for any opportunity record. How does the lookups for contact and lead gets populated? Doesn't it gets the piped data and populates the lookup?

Comment: @RichaTibrewal piped data is for personalization in survey body. Survey response has to be mapped again with parent record like oppty.  https://www.preact.co.uk/blog/how-to-pipe-crm-data-into-voice-of-the-customer-surveys

Comment: Okay. So, how do I populate opportunity in survey response? Creating a workflow won't work because survey is not associated with a particular opty.

Comment: @RichaTibrewal if parent survey is not bound with an oppty record why would child survey responses will be bound with oppty. What if a contact has multiple oppty then you ll send survey on each oppty won so which one to choose & attach. May be in Plugin you can get a top 1 &attach.

Comment: My requirement is to send an email containing the survey link when an opportunity is closed. When I receive survey response, I need to tag it to the same opportunity.

Comment: @RichaTibrewal we are going in circles. Read all the replies in your all SO & Dynamics community threads, you ll get clarified.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181613/discussion-between-richa-tibrewal-and-arun-vinoth).